# is it possible to set a `order` field with the result of ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

**My table_**:

| id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | art2 |
| 2 | art1 |
| 3 | art4 |
| 4 | art3 |

**Expected Update**:

| id | label | order_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | art2 | 2 |
| 2 | art1 | 1 |
| 3 | art4 | 4 |
| 4 | art3 | 3 |

So, I want to set the "*order_*" field with result of

```
SELECT * FROM table_ ORDER BY label ASC;
```

Is it possible with a single request? Or should I just get result and then update "*order_*" in my app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly by using the generic `ORDER BY` clause, though you can achieve that result if the `ORDER BY` clause is found within a window function.

```
SELECT id, 
       label, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY label) AS order_
FROM table_
ORDER BY id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyCzTnkLA5ixh5pEzoJseX/0).

---

If you already have an empty "*order*" field and you need an `UPDATE` statement, you can first craft the `ROW_NUMBER` values separately (inside a subquery), then update your original table by matching on the identifier field.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY label) AS rn
    FROM table_
)
UPDATE     table_
INNER JOIN cte ON table_.id = cte.id 
SET order_ = rn;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyCzTnkLA5ixh5pEzoJseX/1).

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved keyword, so you either have to delimit it in backticks, or else spell it differently as you did in your dbfiddle.